# How do I arrange the results from the TukeyHSD into a table?

Tags: r

I have the output of a TukeyHSD below (turned into a dataframe):

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
comp       diff         lwr        upr     p_adj
duration:5-duration:5              2.125000e-01 -0.13653578  0.5615358 0.4873403
speed:5-probability:5                 2.250000e-01 -0.12403578  0.5740358 0.4219408
probability:10-probability:5          3.875000e-01  0.03846422  0.7365358 0.0206341
duration:10-duration:5             6.875000e-01  0.33846422  1.0365358 0.0000020
speed:10-probability:5                2.250000e-01 -0.12403578  0.5740358 0.4219408
probability:60-probability:5          1.250000e-02 -0.31064434  0.3356443 0.9999974
probability:10-probability:60          1.250000e-02 -0.31064434  0.3356443 0.9999974
probability:10-speed:5          1.250000e-02 -0.31064434  0.3356443 0.9999974
                 ")
```

I want something like below:

```
               duration5 probability5 speed5 duration10 probability10 speed10
duration5 
probability5   p         
speed5         p         p
duration10     p         p            p
probability10  p         p            p      p  
speed10        p         p            p      p          p
```

I already tried a similar solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098321/can-i-arrange-the-results-of-tukeyhsd-into-a-table).

I altered the code to recognize split on hyphens "-", but it doesn't work (see below). Why doesn't it execute? Is there an alternative method?

```
transformTable <- function(tbl, metric) {
  # Takes table of TurkeyHSD output metrics
  # and transforms them into a pairwise comparison matrix.
  # tbl is assumed to be a data.frame or tibble,
  # var is assumed to be a character string
  # giving the variable name of the metric in question
  # (here: "diff", "lwr", "upr", or "p_adj")
  tbl <- tbl %>%
    # Split comparison into individual variables
    mutate(
      Var1 = sub("\\-.*", "", comp), #before hypen
      Var2 = sub(".*-", "", comp)) # after hyphen%>%
    # Only keep relevant fields
    select(Var1, Var2, matches(metric)) %>%
    # Filter out NA's
    filter(!is.na(metric)) %>%
    # Make into "wide" format using Va r2
    spread_(key = 'Var2', value = metric, fill = '')
  
  # Let's change the row names to Var1
  row.names(tbl) <- tbl$Var1
  # And drop the Var1 column
  tbl <- select(tbl, -Var1)
  
  return(tbl)
}
```

```
transformTable(df,'p_adj')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty approach

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)


df <- df %>%
  separate(col = comp, into = c('x', 'y'),  sep = '-') %>%
  mutate(x = str_remove(x, ":")) %>%
  mutate(y = str_remove(y, ":")) %>%
  select(x, y, p_adj)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(unique(c(df$x, df$y))), ncol = length(unique(c(df$x, df$y)))))
colnames(df1) <- unique(c(df$x, df$y))
rownames(df1) <- unique(c(df$x, df$y))

for(i in 1:length(unique(c(df$x, df$y)))){
  for(j in 1:length(unique(c(df$x, df$y)))){
    value <- (df %>% filter(x == rownames(df1)[i]) %>% filter(y == colnames(df1)[j]) %>% select(p_adj))$p_adj
    if(length(value) != 0){
      df1[i,j] <-value
      df1[j,i] <- value
    } 
  }
}
```